# Impossible to customise error message on email field on Sf2

Tags: oop, symfony, symfony-2.0

I modify my code to follow @Stony advices.

I would like to customise my email input error. I try to follow the [symfony2 tutorial](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#form-rendering-template) but it doesn't work.

I follow symfony validation tutorial and I create my yml file, but when I fill my email fiel with bad adress, the error display is still the symfony default error and not my custom message...

```
/**
 *
 * @Route("/info")
 */
class InfoController extends BaseController
{
    public function contactusAction(Request $request)
    {   
    $constraint = new Collection(array('email' => new Email(array('message' => 'Adresse email invalide')),));

    $contact = new ContactUs(); 
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($contact)
        ->add('nom', 'text')
        ->add('mail', 'email')
        ->add('sujet', 'choice', array('choices' => array('pt' => 'Problemes techniques', 'bi' => 'Boite a idees', 'd' => 'Divers')))
        ->add('msg', 'textarea')
        ->getForm();
    }
}
```

Here is my view

```
<form action="" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }} class="contactus">
        {{ form_errors(form) }}
        <div>
            {{ form_label(form.nom, 'Nom : ') }}
            {{ form_errors(form.nom) }}
            {{ form_widget(form.nom) }}
            </div>
            <div>
            {{ form_label(form.mail, 'Email : ') }}
            {{ form_errors(form.mail) }}
            {{ form_widget(form.mail) }}
            </div>
        <div>
            {{ form_label(form.sujet, 'Sujet : ') }}
            {{ form_errors(form.sujet) }}
            {{ form_widget(form.sujet) }}
            </div>
        <div>
            {{ form_label(form.msg, 'Message : ') }}
            {{ form_errors(form.msg) }}
            {{ form_widget(form.msg) }}
            </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Envoyer" />
        {{ form_rest(form) }}
    </form>
```

Here is my yml file

```
PROJECT\CoreBundle\Entity\ContactUs:
    properties:
        mail:
            - Email:
                message: Adresse email invalide.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the error message is very clear:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($contact, array('constraints' => $constraint))
```

there is no second option `constraint`. I don't know what your goal is but this is not the correct way.

If you want some validation you should look at **[Creating Form Classes](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#creating-form-classes)** in your Tutorial. There you can see how you can define Form and Type classes and how to set [validation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#adding-validation) on the fields.

Some more information: [Validation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html)

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#creating-form-classes#adding-validation You can find the line, so constraints option exist, but it doesn't work on my code ;)

Comment: Its the same like validation ;) constraints are used in another way. With a yml file or the constraint classes. The easiest way is to make a validation class and use the annotations.

Comment: But I only want to change the error message of email input, and I would like to do it in my controller. Not in yml file. That's impossible?

Comment: The problem is. "Don't fight the framework" when you work with a framework use the possibilies and split it in different classes and build a structure. Perhaps its easier when you search a Symfony Bundle on Github and look how they do it.

Comment: Look I've updated my post, I create my YML file and put some constraints in it. But when I send my form I've still my error "Please enter an email address" and not "Adresse email invalide"

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`constraints`](http://symfony.com/blog/form-goodness-in-symfony-2-1#custom-field-constraints) option on the `mail` field instead of the form itself.

For Symfony 2.0 use [this](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/forms.html#adding-validation).

Comment: I tried this, ->add('mail', 'email', array('constraints' => $constraint)) but same error message

Comment: I already use this tutorial, and I copy paste the line with constraints option but no result. =/

Comment: I follow some links and I find that [link](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/validation.html#book-validation-raw-values), but where I've to call addEmailFunction?